# Motion in three dimensions with friction.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to represent the motion of an object in three-dimensional space that is undergoing acceleration, friction, and drag, where:

- acceleration = $\vec A$
- friction = $F$
- drag = $D$

The acceleration $\vec A$ is simply a constant to represent gravity and wind.

Friction $F$ represents the force resisting the motion of the object. The acceleration due to friction is a vector of length $F$ opposing the direction of motion:

$-F \left(\frac{\vec V}{\left|\vec V\right|}\right)$.

And drag is a proportional reduction in speed caused by the fluid medium surrounding the object, so the acceleration due to drag is:

$\ln (D) \vec V$.

Combining these, my differential equation looks as follows:

$\vec V'(t)=\vec A -F \left(\frac{\vec V(t)}{\left|\vec V\left(t\right)\right|}\right) +\ln (D)\vec V(t)$

The object also has an initial velocity:

$\vec V(0) = \vec C$.

In general, how do you solve a differential vector equation which includes computing the length of the vector? Can this equation be solved? If so, the solution and an explanation of the steps would be greatly appreciated. I need parametric functions for velocity and position with respect to time.

Comment: the integral of x/|x| of |x| + C, if that helps out